# Can one speaker be used as equivalent of two speakers?

Tags: audio, sound, speakers, multichannel

I have a two channel audio output device for PC. For some reason one of them is broken down. So, I have logically an one channel audio output device. Can I still use it to hear sound outputs belonged to all frequencies from PC by shorting left and right channel wires and feeding it to the working speaker? ***The sound quality may be degraded that way.***

My circuit diagram elaborates it.
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not actually 'shorted', it's known as Bridged Mono. So long as the impedances are still within tolerance, nothing untoward will happen.

Comment: Will it degrade the sound quality?@Tetsujin

Comment: Well, yes, it'll be in mono, not stereo. It's not clear from your post whether it's the output or one speaker that's broken. Text makes me think output, picture makes me think one speaker. If it's the output, it won't be any improvement at all.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it is the left channel speaker(the right one is broken down.), not the output.@Tetsujin

Comment: I thought bridged mono was something very different? Also, wouldn't this cause any out-of-phase content present in both channels to disappear?

Comment: @ToddWilcox Yes, you are right. Actually, I had misconception about the circuit when I asked the question. The circuit I described here will make a short circuited path and damage the sound card as there is usually a phase difference between the signals from two channels and hence voltage difference. N.B.- hence no signal/current will pass through the speaker. So, no sound output. I've attached a picture beneath the previous wrong elaboration so that you can compare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, the stereo signal is just two fast changing voltages and a ground signal and it's totally industry standard plug compatibility for mono stereo jacks to fit suitable speakers.

You can add the two voltages because they have mostly have the same phases of amplitude for most music, with dual mic recordings logically you can get some small phase cancellation effects in certain bass notes if the mics were positioned so that a particular wavelength arrives with inversed phase at either microphone, it's practically unnoticeable, especially in higher frequencies.

Alot of music is made stereo on a mixing desk in so there won't be much phase cancellation.

You will lose the stereo information but all the sound information will still be in the mono signal.